# Calculate total storage per column in table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I was trying to decide how much the total storage is in a big table per column.
There are multiple nvarchar in it.

One column is nvarchar(max) and on importing, the text of an XML is put in it.
After the record is processed correctly. The column is emptied again to an empty string.

In the SQL Server "Disk Usage by Top Tables" report, I see the following.

Amount Records: 1 808 604

Reserved (KB): 15 209 272

Data (KB): 14 466 776

Indexes (KB): 731 896

Unused (KB): 10 600

So I was searching on how to find where this enormous amount of data is in the table. Because the nvarchar(max) columns are almost all empty.

I did a sum(datalength(columnname)) on all the columns in that table.
And made a sum of all the column values.

This gave me: 499 344 838 bytes = 0.499344838 gigabytes

So I'm wondering now:

- Is it not possible to calculate the size of content with sum(datalength(..))
- Is that calculation correct, and where is the other +- 14GB used in the report?

Edit:
I've done some tests with inserting data (see below for loop)

- Insert 10K --> 202.768KB data
- update BATCH set XML = '' where xml <> '' --> 2.768KB data
- Insert 40K --> 813.800KB data
- update BATCH set XML = '' where xml <> '' --> 13.800KB data
- Insert 50K --> 1.027.592 data
- update BATCH set XML = '' where xml <> '' --> 27 592KB data
- ALTER TABLE batch REBUILD WITH (ONLINE = OFF) --> 22 928KB data
- DROP & CREATE table
- Insert 100K with the XML column '' instead of the nvarchar variable --> 22.864KB data

With this test, its not as much data difference, +- 23 vs 27 MB.

I will try to do a rebuild on the production table, but I will need to schedule it.

Edit2: I did a test with loop 1000 times: insert 100 + set xml='' where xml<>''
Result after that is 264.008KB data.
If I do then a rebuild, it goes down to 22.944KB.

So it looks like the rebuild can offer a solution. But any idea on how intensive this can be on a production environment? And if its possible to detect it in my application if I need to execute it?

Table definition with indexes

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[BATCH](
    [BATCH_PID] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [XML_CREATION_DATE] [datetime] NULL,
    [BATCH_REFERENCE] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [SOURCE] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [DOCUMENT_CLASS_FID] [int] NULL,
    [XML_NAME] [nvarchar](150) NULL,
    [XML_TYPE] [int] NULL,
    [XML] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [NUM_OF_DOCUMENTS] [int] NULL,
    [NUM_OF_IMAGES] [int] NULL,
    [PRIORITY] [int] NULL,
    [STATUS] [int] NULL,
    [USER_FID] [int] NULL,
    [EXTENAL_USER] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [REMARKS] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [XML_PATH] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [BATCH_CREATION_DATE] [datetime] NULL,
    [BATCH_PROCESS_DATE] [datetime] NULL,
    [Action] [int] NULL,
    [IMPORT_LOCATION_FID] [bigint] NULL,
    [QUARANTINE_LOCATION_FID] [bigint] NULL,
    [QUARANTINE_DATE] [datetime] NULL,
    [QUARANTINE] [bit] NULL,
    [DOCS_ON_ERROR] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [CAPTURE_XML] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [IGNORE_PAC] [bit] NULL,
    [APPLICATION] [int] NULL,
    [EXTRA_INFO] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [INPUT_TEXT] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [PROCESS_TIME_BATCH] [int] NULL,
    [PROCESS_TIME_DOCUMENT] [int] NULL,
    [PROCESS_TIME_IMAGE] [int] NULL,
    [BATCH_SIZE] [int] NULL,
    [RULES] [nvarchar](1000) NULL,
    [KEEP_XML] [bit] NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [BATCH_PID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]


CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IDX_BATCH_Action] ON [dbo].[BATCH]
(
    [Action] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IDX_BATCH_BATCH_CREATION_DATE] ON [dbo].[BATCH]
(
    [BATCH_CREATION_DATE] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IDX_BATCH_BATCH_SIZE] ON [dbo].[BATCH]
(
    [BATCH_SIZE] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IDX_BATCH_DOCUMENT_CLASS_FID] ON [dbo].[BATCH]
(
    [DOCUMENT_CLASS_FID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IDX_BATCH_IMPORT_LOCATION_FID] ON [dbo].[BATCH]
(
    [IMPORT_LOCATION_FID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IDX_BATCH_PRIORITY] ON [dbo].[BATCH]
(
    [PRIORITY] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IDX_BATCH_PROCESS_TIME_BATCH] ON [dbo].[BATCH]
(
    [PROCESS_TIME_BATCH] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IDX_BATCH_PROCESS_TIME_DOCUMENT] ON [dbo].[BATCH]
(
    [PROCESS_TIME_DOCUMENT] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IDX_BATCH_PROCESS_TIME_IMAGE] ON [dbo].[BATCH]
(
    [PROCESS_TIME_IMAGE] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IDX_BATCH_QUARANTINE] ON [dbo].[BATCH]
(
    [QUARANTINE] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IDX_BATCH_QUARANTINE_LOCATION_FID] ON [dbo].[BATCH]
(
    [QUARANTINE_LOCATION_FID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IDX_BATCH_SOURCE] ON [dbo].[BATCH]
(
    [SOURCE] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IDX_BATCH_STATUS] ON [dbo].[BATCH]
(
    [STATUS] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IDX_BATCH_USER_FID] ON [dbo].[BATCH]
(
    [USER_FID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IDX_BATCH_XML_NAME] ON [dbo].[BATCH]
(
    [XML_NAME] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

I've also created a simple loop to insert data

```
declare @numInserts int = 10000
declare @buildvarchar int = 10000

declare @maxvarchar nvarchar(max) = N'X'

begin

 while @buildvarchar > 0
 begin
  set @maxvarchar = @maxvarchar + N'X'
  set @buildvarchar = @buildvarchar - 1
 end


 while @numInserts > 0
 begin
INSERT [dbo].[BATCH] ([XML_CREATION_DATE], [BATCH_REFERENCE], [SOURCE], [DOCUMENT_CLASS_FID], [XML_NAME], [XML_TYPE], [XML], [NUM_OF_DOCUMENTS], [NUM_OF_IMAGES], [PRIORITY], [STATUS], [USER_FID], [EXTENAL_USER], [REMARKS], [XML_PATH], [BATCH_CREATION_DATE], [BATCH_PROCESS_DATE], [Action], [IMPORT_LOCATION_FID], [QUARANTINE_LOCATION_FID], [QUARANTINE_DATE], [QUARANTINE], [DOCS_ON_ERROR], [CAPTURE_XML], [IGNORE_PAC], [APPLICATION], [EXTRA_INFO], [INPUT_TEXT], [PROCESS_TIME_BATCH], [PROCESS_TIME_DOCUMENT], [PROCESS_TIME_IMAGE], [BATCH_SIZE], [RULES], [KEEP_XML])
VALUES (CAST(N'2017-09-21T14:56:46.000' AS DateTime), N'', N'iDesk', 1, N'21-09-2017-14-44-58-501574', 2, 
@maxvarchar, 0, 0, 1, 9, 1, N'', N'', N'D:\BaseDir\', CAST(N'2017-09-21T14:56:46.000' AS DateTime), CAST(N'2017-09-21T14:56:46.000' AS DateTime), 3, 1, 0, CAST(N'1900-01-01T00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), 0, N'1', NULL, NULL, 4, NULL, N'', 412, 0, 0, 0, N'', 0)

        set @numInserts = @numInserts - 1
    end
end
```

Comment: Are rows ever deleted or updated in this table? (I'm thinking about an un-reclaimed space issue.)

Comment: Not deleted, but the large column is set to =‘’. Is it possible to check if the space can be released?

Comment: That is very similar to a scenario where I was setting a varbinary(max) to null. You may be able to run the test code in this answer for nvarchar(max) and try setting it to an empty string to see if it works, and if not, perhaps consider making it a nullable field since that should mark the space for auto-reuse: https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/183215/86487

Comment: I did a test with setting 100 000 records to NULL instead of ''. But no decrease in size in the report.

Comment: Right. In that question we were focusing on space re-use. The table would stop growing in size and re-use that extra space until it filled it up, and then would start growing again. In most cases that should be fine, but if for some reason you really need to shrink it, DBCC CLEANTABLE might work to decrease the size of a particular table, and DBCC SHRINKFILE may work to decrease the size of the entire DB.

Comment: Can you provide the table declaration for the table in question please? Also, what version of SQL Server are you running?

Comment: What happens if you do an (online if necessary) rebuild of the table? If you think the culprit is in a column not part of ANY index (well, it's always going to be part of the clustered index off course) then use `ALTER TABLE <table_name> REBUILD WITH (ONLINE = [ON|OFF])`, otherwise use `ALTER INDEX ALL ON <table_name> REBUILD WITH (...)` to rebuild everything. Once done the reports DATA part should show more or less the sum of the datalengths I think. Due to the way records are aligned in pages + the concept of FILLFACTOR, the reserved space will always be higher, but not 14Gb vs .5Gb imho.

Comment: I've added info in the start post.
The customers SQL version is 13.0.4435.0. My local test DB is 14.0.2002.14.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the following statement, I managed to decrease the table size with 27GB.

ALTER TABLE batch REBUILD WITH (ONLINE = OFF)

Looks like SQL isn’t re-using the space automatically.

I did not find a solution on how to detect if it will clean something in advance. The sum datalength query difference was like 400MB difference.

Answer (score 2):

> •Is it not possible to calculate the size of content with
>   sum(datalength(..))

Create table with only one column and one value.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[BATCH2] ([BATCH_PID] INT)

INSERT INTO [BATCH2] VALUES (1)



SELECT DATALENGTH(BATCH_PID) FROM BATCH2
```

This will return 4 ,as we know that `INT Storage` is `4 byte`.

If we use, `sp_spaceused BATCH2`

You will notice data column is 8KB. Why ?

As we know data is store in Page, and each page occupy 8KB.

so in our example even one row will need 1 Page i.e 8KB.

So datalength will give you size data .

> •Is that calculation correct, and where is the other +- 14GB used in
>   the report?

If we insert 10000 rows at first time,then say delete / update some rows of varies length ,then `sp_spaceused BATCH2` may not return correct value because Memory is not reclaim with `Insert/Update/Delete`.When we delete some rows or update some rows then there may be some unused memory in Pages or there may me more pages because of large update.

But it won't reflect immediately.

So from time to time we need to `Rebuild Index` specially table with so many indexes.

So once we Rebuild indexes, Index are orgainise and data are organise in data pages and index pages, lost memory is reclaim.

```
ALTER INDEX ALL ON [dbo].[BATCH] reorganize
```

So `sp_spaceused BATCH`  will give correct data now.